# Can you use a NLB address in a MSMQ call?

Tags: biztalk, msmq, biztalk-2010, nlb

Can you use a NLB address in a MSMQ call?

We have three BizTalk servers, with a NLB address for them.

Would a MSMQ call to the NLB address, rather than the individual server address work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible and it is easy to setup (or even without any configuration) if you are using Non-transactional messaging.

> Message Queuing is supported in an NLB environment for both sending and receiving messages in the following configurations:
>
> - Non-transactional messaging by using Direct=TCP
> - Non-transactional messaging by using Direct=OS with validation disabled
> - Non-transactional messaging by using Direct=HTTP
> - Transactional messaging by using a specific configuration that uses store and
>     forward servers and a single backend server

Microsoft provides an excellent article about this topic: [How Message Queuing can function over Network Load Balancing (NLB)](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/899611/en-us)